# Get the specific value only from a string to display in textbox C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms

The string contains this value:

> 3/14/1952 12:00:00 AM

Now I want to show only in text box the date not the time how can I do this?

> 3/14/1952

Comment: I would like to prefer to use `Substring`. `sValue.Substring(sValue.IndexOf(" "))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that will give you array of strings and your required date string is at `zero` index.

```
string date = str.Split(' ')[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

I think most secure way is to parsing it to `DateTime` with [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method and using [`"d"` standard date and time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ShortDate) .

As an example;

```
string s = "3/14/1952 12:00:00 AM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s,
                                  "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d"));
```

Output will be;

```
3/14/1952
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/WcaxOX)</kbd>.

After parsing process, you can use this value in your `TextBox` with `.Text` property like;

```
TextBox1.Text = dt.ToString("d");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Since you are using space for splitting, you don't have to specify the space character.

```
string MyString ="3/14/1952 12:00:00 AM";
string date=MyString.Split()[0];
```

OR

```
string date=MyString.Split().First();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions:
1. parse it to datetime and then convert it to your string format

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse("3/14/1952 12:00:00 AM");
var yourString = datetime.ToString("M/dd/yyyy");
```

2. just split it by string.Split method

```
string yourString = str.Split(' ')[0];
```